# Windows 10 Deployment: Sysprep failed to validate

Tags: windows-10, sysprep, imaging

I am attempting to capture a reference image of a Windows 10 machine.  It is Windows 10 Education x64.  **I did a clean install** and then added the apps I needed.

Now when I try to run sysprep

```
sysprep.exe /generalize /oobe /shutdown /unattend:C:\unattend.xml
```

I find myself running into this error:
[Sysprep error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErYxE.jpg)
In case that image doesn't work (seems not to work just now) here is another link to the [same error](https://www.okanozbey.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/sysprep-error.png).

From what I can find online it seems that this error typically is thrown when one attempts to run sysprep on a system that has been upgraded (not a clean install).  There is a registry hack to get around that, but I don't even have the applicable keys (it is a clean install).  I'll need a different solution.

I do not have Candy Crush Soda or Twitter installed.  I even clicked their icons (which installs them) and then manually uninstalled them just to be sure they are gone and the issue persists.

I have tried to read the setupact.log file, but for some reason it seems that Windows is no longer writing to that log file when I try to run Sysprep.  Not sure why.

Please share any insights you may have.  Thanks!